# CSS transition animation order issue for accordion

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-transitions

I have exampled below two div boxes with `<h4>` headers and followed with `<p>` with text. In an accordion style, I want to click each title and see the text appear, I've done this by setting the text div container box to `max-height: 0;` and `opacity: 0;` then max height a value and opacity 1 on click.

My **issue** is that I expect the animation to happen simultaneously for both boxes (one that slides up and hides, the other that slides down and appears), However, I get the animation running in order slide up and disappear forwarded by slide down and appear.

How can I get them both at the same time?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // main click handler for the whole page
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    var clickedElem = event.target;

    if (clickedElem.matches(".slide-card h4")) {

      var activeCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card-active");

      if (activeCards) {
        for (var i = 0; i < activeCards.length; i++) {
          if (activeCards[i]) toggle(activeCards[i], "card-active");
        }
      }

      toggle(clickedElem.parentNode, "card-active");
    }
  });
});


function toggle(el, elClass) {
  if (el.matches("." + elClass)) {
    el.classList.remove(elClass);
  } else {
    el.classList.add(elClass);
  }
}
```

```css
h4 {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.slide-card {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1em;
}

.animated-slides-cards {
  background: pink;
  padding: 1em;
}

.card-body {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.card-active .card-body {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-slides-cards">
  <div data="0" class="slide-card block-padding margin-bottom-05x card-active">
    <h4 class="blue">Harness the power of the crowd</h4>
    <div class="grey card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam mattis eros vitae metus sodales eget suscipit purus rhoncus. Proin ultrices gravida dolor, non porttitor enim interdum vitae. Integer feugiat lacinia tincidunt. Nulla laoreet tristique
        tristique. Sed elementum justo a nisl elementum sit amet accumsan nisi tempor. Nulla quis eros et massa dignissim imperdiet a vitae purus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data="1" class="slide-card block-padding margin-bottom-05x">
    <h4 class="blue">Slots straight into your systems</h4>
    <div class="grey card-body">
      <p>Using simple APIs, SmartCrowd™ connects to your systems and allocates tasks to ambassadors using your existing digital channels. You can opt for full integration or simply use Limitless Live Messenger on your website to maintain a single customer
        view.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think, that you should just do something to make fading out a bit faster. I am not into CSS stuff too much, so I will not provide you with any code, but that where I would search for it. For me this appears to be working fine. The animations starts at the same time. Just looks odd because the div will not change its size before all text will fade-out completely.

Comment: think you nailed it there, it DOES look odd doesnt it. I want it to fade and slide up at the same time, this is the expected behaviour. So not really sure why it seems to fade and then slide up the height of the container div... wonder if this is implemenation issue (probably), or CSS bug?

Comment: Yes. The fact, that it is firstly fading completely then resizing is expected, because it would make still fading text going out of the box and it would look even more odd.

Comment: You could delete some text from `innerText` of your box to make it smaller, but you would have to play with `setInterval()` and time it almost perfectly, which would be ery hard to do. Especially when considering different sizes of viewport, which can make all sorts of disalignments with sizing box.

Comment: Of course you would then have the backup of the text saved somewhere in your code to restore it when needed.

Comment: what? No, I asked CSS to change the max-height and opacity at the same time, my question is why isn't it doing it?